# Need help for installing windows and ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

wanted to do dual boot.So, for that, using windows 8.1,First of all I shrinked one of my partition to 70 GB and made a 35 GB space for ubuntu install. Using Ubuntu install menu I set the 35 Gb hard disk to ext4 as suggested by internet forums. Then I installed ubuntu and it said me to restart to proceed. So, when I restarted I didn't get my windows 8.1. I needed the windows back so to get it back using a bootable cd I formated Ubuntu partition so that I could get my Windows back. When I did it, this is what i got. I think I lost my windows did I? please help me for dual boot.
(https://imageshack.com/i/pb6W48zAp)

Comment: Did you shrink the Windows partition with a Windows program or gparted?

Comment: i did it with windows partition

Comment: If you haven't formatted the Windows partition, the OS should still be there. It's just that the boot loader is incorrectly configured. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the boot loader to help you. You could try Unbutu's Boot Repair program https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of questions about it. After you install Ubuntu, you should open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then GRUB (the Ubuntu boot manager) will search in all of your partitions and will create menu entries with the OSs it finds.

When the update-grub command is done, reboot and you should see Windows in your GRUB menu (if you did not format your Windows partition, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend First try for updating grub by following command

> sudo update-grub

If not showing the correct result  then do following procedure.

I think  you have formatted the whole drive of 70gbAnd 35gb shrink from another one coz it showing whole 70gb drive and 35gb alsoI think the unallocated space says that your Windows os is formatted. So do clean installation of Windows anf then re shrink it and covert them into 3 logical partitions i.e.

> /  type ext4 size as you require
>
> swap type swap area
>
> /home type ext4